# problem with face_recognition package: _UFuncNoLoopError: 'subtract' with signature matching types (dtype('<U2080'), dtype('float64'))

Tags: python, numpy, face-recognition

So i'm trying to make a facial recognition system for my school project . Step 1 : The software primarly reads a bunch of images gets there names and Facial data (encodings to recognize who is who) and stores them in CSV file . Step 2 :  After that another part of the software opens the csv file and stores the names from the CSV file as list('name_of_people') and Facial Data as list('knownEncodedList') . Now in step 1 if store the face readings and names in a list the code works fine , but when i store them in a csv and then try using them the code throws this erro .   Link of the repository: https://github.com/ZahinFyz/Face_Recognition

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\This Semester\Python\Projects\Face Recognition\Face_recognition.py", line 47, in <module>
    matches = fr.compare_faces(knownEncodedList , encodeFaceF)
  File "F:\This Semester\Python\Projects\Face Recognition\venv\lib\site-packages\face_recognition\api.py", line 226, in compare_faces
    return list(face_distance(known_face_encodings, face_encoding_to_check) <= tolerance)
  File "F:\This Semester\Python\Projects\Face Recognition\venv\lib\site-packages\face_recognition\api.py", line 75, in face_distance
    return np.linalg.norm(face_encodings - face_to_compare, axis=1)
numpy.core._exceptions._UFuncNoLoopError: ufunc 'subtract' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U2080'), dtype('float64')) -> None
```

The actual code :

```
import cv2
import csv
import face_recognition as fr
import numpy as np

name_of_people = []
with open('Facial Data.csv') as data :
    data = csv.reader(data)
    next(data)
    for col in data :
        name_of_people.append(col[0])



#file = open("Facial Data.csv")
#numpy_array = np. loadtxt(file, delimiter=",")
#print(numpy_array)


knownEncodedList = []
with open('Facial Data.csv') as data :
    data = csv.reader(data)
    next(data)
    for col in data :
        encode = np.array(col[1])
        knownEncodedList.append(encode)

#Use to get video steam from camera
'''https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-opencv-capture-video-
from-camera/#:~:text=Use%20cv2.,the%20frames%20in%20the%20video.'''
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True :
    '''https://stackoverflow.com/
    questions/65535939/python-understanding-read-in-opencv'''
    success , img = cap.read()
    #Resiving the image so that it doesn't take much time to read
    imgS = cv2.resize(img,(0,0),None , 0.25 , 0.25)

    facesInF = fr.face_locations(imgS)
    encInF = fr.face_encodings(imgS,facesInF)

    #sequentially grab face locations and face encodings of the video
    for encodeFaceF , facelocF in zip(encInF,facesInF):

        #matching with our given data set
        matches = fr.compare_faces(knownEncodedList , encodeFaceF)
        faceDis = fr.face_distance(knownEncodedList , encodeFaceF)

        #getting the best match
        matchIndex = np.argmin(faceDis)
        z = np.min(faceDis)
        #print(matchIndex)
        if z < 0.45 :
            #Designing the Frame
            if matches[matchIndex]:
                name = name_of_people[matchIndex]
                y1,x2,y2,x1 = facelocF
                y1, x2, y2, x1 = y1*4,x2*4,y2*4,x1*4
                cv2.rectangle(img,(x1 , y1),(x2,y2),(0,255,0),2)
                cv2.rectangle(img,(x1,y2-35),(x2,y2),(0,255,0),cv2.FILLED)
                cv2.putText(img , name,(x1+6 , y2-6),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX,1,(255,255,255),2)
                print(name)
        else :
            name = 'Tresspasser'
            y1, x2, y2, x1 = facelocF
            y1, x2, y2, x1 = y1 * 4, x2 * 4, y2 * 4, x1 * 4
            cv2.rectangle(img, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (128,0,0), 2)
            cv2.rectangle(img, (x1, y2 - 35), (x2, y2), (128,0,0), cv2.FILLED)
            cv2.putText(img, name, (x1 + 6, y2 - 6), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 1, (255, 255, 255),2)


    cv2.imshow('webcam' ,img)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

So the software is supposed to get the names and readings from the csv file and when it sees a face it can detect the person and show his name . I tried using genfromtxt() and loadtxt() but couldn't get to bring the data from csv properly

Comment: contact the author of the repository. [tour], [ask], [mre]. debug your code. inspect `face_encodings`

Answer (score 0):

when you try to unpack the csv file, meaning you want to get the two lists separately, the form of the list changes or something, so the solution is to not unpack anything just rewrite this:

```py
KnownEncodingsList = []

def findEncodings(imagList):

    encodeList = []
    for img in imagList:
        img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        encode = face_recognition.face_encodings(img)[0]
        encodeList.append(encode)

    return encodeList

KnownEncodingsList = findEncodings(imagesList)
```

based on your variables names and you lists names , meaning you should not make python get you the list from the csv file, instead , you give it the list again so that it is used as it is . Now the looping becomes correct and has no errors , also make sure the images have the same size. this is an alternative solution.I think if you use pickle instead of csv, you wont get the error, but i guess you should be using pyCharm not VScode.